# How to get DLLs, function names, and addresses from the Import Table with PortEx?

Tags: java, portable-executable, disassembly

I'm using the [PortEx Java library for PE32 parsing](https://github.com/katjahahn/PortEx) with the Capstone disassembler, and I'd like to be able to have the disassembly replace the appropriate `call 0x404040` lines to be something like `call SomeDLL:TheFunc`. To do this, I need the imports from the Import Table. I am able to get the DLL name and function, but the address reported by PortEx is way off, ex: 0x32E8 vs. 0x402004 as reported by the pefile Python module. I have tried looking at some of the offsets as part of the `ImportSection`, `ImportDLL`, and `NameImport` classes in PortEx, but it doesn't get close. The Any thoughts?

```
import com.github.katjahahn.parser.*;
public class ImportsExtractor {
    public static Map<Integer,String> extract(PEData exe) throws IOException {
        Map<Integer,String> importList = new HashMap<>();

        SectionLoader loader = new SectionLoader(exe);
        ImportSection idata = loader.loadImportSection();
        List<ImportDLL> imports = idata.getImports();
        for(ImportDLL dll : imports) {
            for(NameImport nameImport : dll.getNameImports()) {
                long addr = nameImport.getRVA(); // Some offset needed?
                System.out.format("0x%X\t%s:%s%n", addr, dll.getName(), nameImport.getName());
                importList.put((int)addr, dll.getName() + ":" + nameImport.getName());
            }
        }
        return importList;
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to grab the address from a line of assembly, see if it's in `importList`, and if so, replace the address with the value in `importList`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the author:

```
public static Map<Integer,String> extract(PEData exe) throws IOException {
    Map<Integer,String> importList = new HashMap<>();

    SectionLoader loader = new SectionLoader(exe);
    ImportSection idata = loader.loadImportSection();
    List<ImportDLL> imports = idata.getImports();
    for(ImportDLL dll : imports) {
        for(NameImport nameImport : dll.getNameImports()) {
            long iat = nameImport
                    .getDirEntryValue(DirectoryEntryKey.I_ADDR_TABLE_RVA);
            long ilt = nameImport
                    .getDirEntryValue(DirectoryEntryKey.I_LOOKUP_TABLE_RVA);
            long imageBase = exe.getOptionalHeader().get(
                    WindowsEntryKey.IMAGE_BASE);
            long addr = nameImport.getRVA() + imageBase;
            if(ilt != 0) addr = addr - ilt + iat;
            System.out.format("0x%X\t%s:%s%n", addr, dll.getName(), nameImport.getName());
            importList.put((int)addr, dll.getName() + ":" + nameImport.getName());
        }
    }

    return importList;
}
```